# Using conditional in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

Here is my jsfiddle link and I am trying to print below DropDown a message - "Select option B"  when any option other than B is selected.

When Option B is selected , I have to print Id and option Name

http://jsfiddle.net/fortm/MGX9k/1/

What is happening is that "Select Option B" message is never getting printed. Always Id and Name is being shown.

So, there is some problem with Handlebar conditional -

```
{{#if App.SearchController.selectedB}}
```

Where , selectedB is a function that returns true when Option is B, but this seems to be not working..

```
  selectedB: function() {
    return this.get('selectedName.id') == 2 ;
  }
```

As a side question , I needed to style Select Dropdown and so I added "class" atrribute. It got custom styled but it still has ember-select as one of styles.. Can we remove ember CSS  when adding a new own style ?

Comment: Thanks MilkyWayJoe and emk and I wished I could accept both as answers. Using router is really elegant and ember-data tip is noted.

Comment: No problem! It was an interesting debugging challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see here isn't much about the conditional itself, but with how you're using your data. A few things:

(You can see more here: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/enRhT/)

If you want your template to react on `selectedB`, you have to make it into a [computed property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html), also specifying its dependencies, which in your case is the `selectedName` property:

```
selectedB: function() {
    return this.get('selectedName.id') == 2;
}.property('selectedName') // This is important
```

Also, I've noticed that in your templates you are assigning your bindings to the controller class and not the instance. Consider changing your application to include the `Router`, which will allow you to set your model data differently.

With the routing mechanism, a controller will be assigned to your route and bound to the view/template automatically, so instead of binding to `App.SearchController.property`, you can do it with `controller` or `controller.property`:

```
{{view Ember.Select class="my_custom_class"
    contentBinding="controller.content"
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
    selectionBinding="controller.selectedName"}}
```

This would require a few more changes tho.

**Setting up the Router**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('search');
});
// this would require that you either create an IndexRoute 
// to redirect from the root to the SearchRoute, or
// change the route path: this.route('search', { path: '/' });
```

**returning data from the route's model function and not from controller**

```
App.SearchRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [
            {firstName: "Any",  id: 0},
            {firstName: "A",    id: 1},
            {firstName: "B",    id: 2},
            {firstName: "C",    id: 3},
            {firstName: "D",    id: 4},
            {firstName: "E",    id: 5}
        ];
    }
});
```

**Adding an `{{outlet}}` to the application template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{outlet}}
</script>
```

**moving your template body to a specific template, using the correct `controller`**

Now, because the route is providing the controller and its data, you should be able to use the `controller` key in your Handlebars template, and it will refer to the SearchController (see below).

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="search">
    {{view Ember.Select class="my_custom_class"
       contentBinding="controller.content"
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
       selectionBinding="controller.selectedName"}}

    {{#if selectedB}}
      <p>Selected: {{controller.selectedName.firstName}}
      (ID: {{controller.selectedName.id}})</p>
    {{else}}
    <p>Select option B</p>
    {{/if}}    
</script>
```

**Fixing controller**

```
App.SearchController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectedName: null,
  selectedB: function() {
    return this.get('selectedName.id') == 2 ;
  }.property('selectedName')
});
```

Because of [naming conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/#toc_nesting), your route expects your app to have a `SearchController` (this exact name), and that's how it connects everything together. And if your controller doesn't implement an `ArrayController`, it will blow up since your model function now returns a `ModelArray` and it wouldn't bind to an `ObjectController` (default)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/ekidd/MGX9k/11/). Here's a few of the most important things I changed:

1. I moved your content setup in `SearchRoute` where it belongs:

   ```
   App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function () {
       return [
         Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Any", id: 0}),
   ```
2. I fixed your search controller to use `extend` instead of `create`, and made `selectedB` a computed property:

   ```
   App.SearchController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     selectedName: null,

     selectedB: function() {
       // Be careful! If you use Ember Data, the key will be '2', not 2.
       return this.get('selectedName.id') === 2;
     }.property("selectedName.id")
   });
   ```
3. I gave `SearchController` its own template, and modified the code to use relative properties instead of trying to access the controller as a global. I also hooked up `contentBinding` to point at your search controller, which acts as a proxy for your actual content.

   ```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="search">

     {{view Ember.Select class="my_custom_class"
            contentBinding="this"
            optionValuePath="content.id"
            optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
            selectionBinding="selectedName"}}
   ```

There were some other minor changes, too.